# Android studio, Metodo Switch trava o app

Tags: java, android, switch

to tendo um problema com o Switch do Android studio, simplesmente não consigo fazer nem uma manipulação com o dado dele porque simplesmente trava o App na VM.

MAIN.Java[image: tem um botão de navegação mas ja fiz os Fragments tudo certinho]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

uma duvida, essas alterações são na MAIN.JAVA ou na Fragment?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. [***Não poste código como imagem.***](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/60376) Faça o [tour] para saber como funciona a **comunidade**, caso necessite de ajuda, acesse a [help].

Comment: Qual método que dispara o erro? Poderia mostrar o erro?